# Connect two datasets with left_join

Tags: r, left-join

I’m trying to connect/merge the following datasets, "merged_data" and "GpsData" with function `left_join()`, but I’m coming in front of some obstacles.

Code:

```
> new_obj1<-lapply(merged_data, head)
> dput(head(new_obj1))
list(Country = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8), `Country Name` = c("England",
"Costa Rica", "Italy", "India", "Namibia", "Czech Republic"),
    `Uncertainty Avoidance Societal Practices` = c(4.65123456790123,
    3.82456140350877, 3.78755868544601, 4.1504854368932, 4.2,
    4.43958333333333), `Future Orientation Societal Practices` = c(4.27901234567901,
    3.60350877192982, 3.25258215962441, 4.19271844660194, 3.49333333333333,
    3.63041666666667), `Power Distance Societal Practices` = c(5.15308641975309,
    4.73684210526316, 5.4268779342723, 5.46601941747573, 5.29333333333333,
    3.58875), `Collectivism I Societal Practices (Institutional Collectivism)` = c(4.27160493827161,
    3.92982456140351, 3.67899061032864, 4.38106796116505, 4.13333333333333,
    3.60486111111111))

> new_obj2<-lapply(GpsData, head)
> dput(head(new_obj2))
list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia",
"Austria", "Bangladesh"), isocode = c("AFG", "DZA", "ARG", "AUS",
"AUT", "BGD"), patience = c(-0.201360121369362, 0.0598152466118336,
-0.229307979345322, 0.65700376033783, 0.608285009860992, 0.0811367109417915
), risktaking = c(0.120764262974262, 0.391530483961105, 0.0415031686425209,
0.137136548757553, -0.0618291534483433, -0.198067754507065),
    posrecip = c(0.2896409034729, -0.598255336284637, 0.159679308533669,
    0.069660022854805, 0.161046594381332, 0.154367566108704),
    negrecip = c(0.254712462425232, 0.254900813102722, -0.140457272529602,
    0.0221897512674332, -0.0554154515266418, 0.113288171589375
    ))
```

*I have used this "reference_iso":*

```
> reference_iso <- read.csv("C:/Users/ILIAS/Documents/Dissertation/Data/iso3.csv", encoding = 'UTF-8')[,c(1,3)]
> dput(head(reference_iso))
structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania",
"Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra"), alpha.3 = c("AFG", "ALA",
"ALB", "DZA", "ASM", "AND")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Above I have given you a sample of my datasets, "merged_data" and "GpsData".

I have tried to merge them with function `left_join`:

```
all_data <- GpsData %>%
  left_join(reference_iso, by = c('country' = 'name')) %>%
  rename(iso3 = 'alpha.3') %>%
  left_join(merged_data, by = c('iso3' = 'Country Name') )
```

But as you can see, this process doesn’t work correctly.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to recode you data variables and try to use *data.frame*.

The list is not good for joining data.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data, `new_obj1` & `GpsData` are of class list. That is why you are not able to use `left_join`.

Try converting those lists into dataframes as in code below and try to run your joining code again.

```
df_merged_data <- bind_rows(merged_data)
df_GpsData <- bind_rows(GpsData)
```

```
all_data <- df_GpsData %>%
  left_join(reference_iso, by = c('country' = 'name')) %>%
  rename(iso3 = 'alpha.3') %>%
  left_join(df_merged_data, by = c('iso3' = 'Country Name') )
```

Comment: the change you suggested me above to make and use didnt work and im facing the same problems, missing values in many columns

Comment: can you share the error that you are facing, are you sure you are changing in your code the object names after converting them to data.frame?